# Querying multiple Postgres tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that I would like to make to multiple tables and then join the results at the end.

This works, but I was hoping there was a more concise way of achieving the same thing

```
SELECT key, a.c as "TableA count", b.c as "TableB count", c.c as "TableC count", d.c as "TableD count"
FROM
(
    SELECT key, count(key) as c
    FROM table_a
    WHERE data = 'foo'
    GROUP BY key
) a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT key, count(key) as c
    FROM table_b
    WHERE data = 'foo'
    GROUP BY key
) b USING(key)
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT key, count(key) as c
    FROM table_c
    WHERE data = 'foo'
    GROUP BY key
) c USING(key)
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT key, count(key) as c
    FROM table_d
    WHERE data = 'foo'
    GROUP BY key
) d USING(key);
```

Expected Output:

```
 key |  A count |  B count | C  count |  D count |
-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
5740 |        5 |      102 |      129 |          |
5741 |     1017 |    22163 |    34888 |      218 |
5742 |      797 |    10846 |    19285 |      159 |
5743 |    24966 |   398067 |   572504 |     4772 |
5744 |    31942 |   278944 |    73628 |     5665 |
5745 |     3975 |    54322 |    98578 |     1103 |
5746 |     1353 |     4751 |    33129 |      259 |
```

Comment: I can't think of a more concise way other to suggest that if you had just table for all the data the query could be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think than if you are using `key` to join that tables is because `key` is in the same domain (in a conceptually way at least).

If you have or could have a table with all `key` values in a `PK` you can do something better.

### Partial solution

**Only if `key` is the primary key of a table**

```
SELECT key, total_a, total_b, total_c, total_d
   FROM key_table, 
        lateral (
          SELECT count(key) as total_a
          FROM table_a
          WHERE key = key_table.key AND data = 'foo'
        ) a,
        lateral (
          SELECT count(key) as total_b
          FROM table_b
          WHERE key = key_table.key AND data = 'foo'
        ) b,
        lateral (
          SELECT count(key) as total_c
          FROM table_c
          WHERE key = key_table.key AND data = 'foo'
        ) c,
        lateral (
          SELECT count(key) as total_d
          FROM table_d
          WHERE key = key_table.key AND data = 'foo'
        ) d
    WHERE total_a IS NOT NULL OR total_b IS NOT NULL OR  total_c IS NOT NULL OR  total_d IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY key
```

### Changing model solution

Other solution is to change the data model having table_Ls data in the same table. For existing queries you can have views. This is a good solution if the table_L tables are in the same domain (for example cities of diferent countries) and the columns are the same (or have minimal differences).

The new table must have a new field `source_data` with the values `'a', 'b', 'c', d'` and the four views are like:

```
 CREATE VIEW table_a AS 
   SELECT key, foo, others_field1, other_field2, ...
     FROM table_abcd
     WHERE source_data = 'a'
   WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Doing this you can do similar things. The main problem is the Foreign keys to the table_L tables, if you have that you may do the same with the related tables.

**look at**: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS

### Triggering data to another table

If the tables are in different domains and this query is very importan you can trigger that data in anohter table. For example `key` is the username of the person that adds the data (and you want to pay to him for that), and table_L are very different things.

You can add a trigger to each table_L table to trigger an update to other table `recolected_data` with the needed fields (incluiding `source_table` field) and then query with a simple `group by` query.